# OCR (tesseract), intelligent rotation for Image

Tags: android, rotation, ocr, tesseract

I'm developing an Android app which uses tesseract OCR to recognize Text, now I have the Problem that on different Smartphones the image gets rotate in a different way, so on one it is in landscape mode right away and on the other in portrait mode. So now i want to intelligently rotate the Image so that Tesseract can recognize the Text. Which is only in one of the two options possible, but it might be in either, due to the user taking the picture. I don't want the User to have to take the picture in the same format everytime, i want to rotate it so it fits the need, if possible without too much of a performance loss.

The Tesseract lib with the autorotate does not seem to work for me in that way. 
Anybody an idea how to solve that problem.

Thanks

Comment: Tessarct lib didnt provide auto rotate functionality.

You have to put your logic for that.

Comment: Check out Tesseract's [Orientation and script detection (OSD)](http://code.google.com/p/tesseract-ocr/wiki/APIExample) example. The orientation and deskew angle may be of your interest. You'll have to rotate the image accordingly.

Answer (score 2):

If this question is still relevant for you: Maybe you can extract the exif data of the image, to get its orientation?

Otherwise this paper maybe can help you: [Combined Orientation and Script Detection using the Tesseract OCR Engine](http://research.google.com/pubs/pub35506.html).

Answer (score 1):

If you don't mind rolling your sleeves up, http://www.leptonica.org/ is probably a good option to evaluate the glyphs (raw Pix that is not detected as text yet) and determine orientation.  I've seen references to Android bindings for Leptonica.